# Fetch data from Sqlite database

Tags: android

I am creating app in which i register user and store user's information in database,so i have created database and storing value in databse but i don't know how to fetch data from database and show in textview?Using below query to fetch data but it has error.What is correct way?

```
 public void insertEntry(String fname, String lname, String gen,String weight)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("firstname", fname);
    values.put("lastname", lname);
    values.put("gender", gen);
    values.put("weight",weight);
}

public Cursor fetchData()
{
    SQLiteDatabase mDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    return mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  Register WHERE firstname=? lastname =?"  , null);
}
```

Using this to set fetched value on textview in different activity

```
Cursor name = sqliteDataBase.fetchData();
    tv_name.setText((CharSequence) name);
```

Comment: use Suger ORM library for database

Comment: what is the error u r getting? Check this SELECT * FROM  Register WHERE firstname=? lastname =?"  , null in this line u r expecting 2 params but u r passing null is it fine?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
try {
    SQLiteDatabase mDB = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM  Register WHERE firstname= "+first+" lastname =" + last + ";";

                cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

                if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                     String firstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("firstname")));
                    }
                }
} catch(Exception e) {
e.printSTackTrace();
} finally {
if (cursor != null) {
cursor.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public String fecthResults()
 {
   String name = null;

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
           name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("firstname")
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return name;
```

Get the name and then set it directly to a texView

Answer (score 0):

A `Cursor` is an interface that provides random read-write access to the result set returned by the query. It contains multiple rows of data and this data can be easily processed by help of `For` loop.

Lets take an example to understand the process. Suppose, you need to access data from a column name "col_1" and show the data in `TextView`. The `For` loop for the process will be as follows.

```
for (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("col_1")));
}
```

Now, if we need only one value (from only one record or tuple) then, we can opt out the `For` loop and change the code as shown below.

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("col_1")));
}
```

**Always remember to close the cursor after using it.**

To close the cursor, use the following line of code.

```
cursor.close();
```

For more information, please visit the following links:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#ReadDbRow